# Why is always passing the expect command?

Tags: javascript, protractor, chai

I am reading a text from a website in order to compare it with the string 'test'. It should fail, however, it passes. Why?

See the piece of code below:

```
expect(el.get(i).getText()).to.be.eventually.equal('test');
```

where element el is:

```
var el=$$('*[class="panel-body"] p');
```

The definition of expect is:

```
global.expect = require('chai').expect;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`to.be.eventually.equal` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Did you maybe mean

```
should.eventually.equal
```

or

```
to.eventually.equal
```

Comment: What about `should.eventually.equal`?

Comment: It says something like that:
 E/launcher - { __flags: 
   { ssfi: [Function: proxyGetter],
     lockSsfi: undefined,
     object: 
      { browser_: [Object],
        then: [Function],
        parentElementArrayFinder: [Object],
        elementArrayFinder_: [Object],
        click: [Function],
        sendKeys: [Function],
        getTagName: [Function],

Answer (score 0):

You need to use package `chai-as-promise` to handle promise.

```
var chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
global.expect = chai.expect;
```

Comment: same behaviour :(

Comment: Make sure your `chai` are compatible with `chai-as-promised`